# Best way to model List of unknown length, containing pairs of enum?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to work out the best way to add pairs of data on the fly:

```
  enum Enums
    {
        blue,
        green,
        red,
        yellow
    }

List<List<Enums>> comboEnums = new List<List<Enums>>();

List<Enums> twoColors = new List<Enums>();

twos.Add(Enums.blue);
twos.Add(Enums.green);

comboEnums.Add(twoColors);
```

That works fine for one pair, but adding any extra pairs just appends them to the comboEnums list obviously.

What I want is for each placeholder of comboEnums to have a new instance of twoColors. I can see possible ways of doing it, but not experienced enough to know which is best. This is just for a project, not a real application.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. What is "each placeholder of comboEnums"? If you have some possible ways, then include them. If the code is already working you might do better at [codereview.se]

Comment: May be you are looking for Tuple?

Comment: Combination of two colors only? Or more?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure on the question, but what about flags?

```
[Flags]
enum Colours
{
    none = 0,
    blue = 1,
    green = 2,
    red = 4,
    yellow = 8
}

List<Colours> comboColours = new List<Colours>();

//get a variable to hold our colours
var twoColours;

//add blue to the variable
twoColours |= Colours.blue;

//add green to the variable
twoColours |= Colours.green;


//add the colour to our collection
comboColours.Add(twoColours);
```

If you need each pair to be unique, use a Dictionary instead of a List.